# Is there a specific mention object for commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So right now I'm trying to figure out how to make my bot mention the role/member/everyone/here mention when a user uses it in a command but there is an issue. I can either make it so that it recognises roles or members separately. Is there a way to ignore that and just get whatever mention the user uses?

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def announce(ctx, tit : str = None, desc : str =  None, user : discord.Role = None):
  if tit and desc:
    if mention:
      await ctx.channel.send(content = user.mention)
```

Whenever I use it on @here, for example, I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.RoleNotFound: Role "@​here" not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) and [`Message.role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.role_mentions), which are lists of mention and role objects.

For @everyone and @here, you can use [`Message.mention_everyone`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mention_everyone). Unfortunately this is only a `bool` and not an object. This is `True` if either @everyone or @here is mentioned.

[`Message.channel_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel_mentions) can also be checked for a list of channel and thread objects.

```py
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def announce(ctx, tit : str = None, desc : str =  None):
    if tit and desc:
        for mention in ctx.message.mentions:
            await ctx.channel.send(content = mention)
        for role_mention in ctx.message.role_mentions:
            await ctx.channel.send(content = role_mention)
        for channel_mention in ctx.message.channel_mentions:
            await ctx.channel.send(content = channel_mention)
        if ctx.message.mention_everyone:
            await ctx.channel.send('everyone or here was mentioned')
```